# Selecting Previous and Current value based on change

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select previous and current customer for a product from the following tables. PREV_DAY table contains the latest customer set on previous day for a product and the CURR_DAY table sets the subsequent changes. RANKING column shows the order of changes where value 1 is the latest change. So what I am trying to do is for product 100, the changes at the end of CURR_DAY should be,

```
**PREV_CUST** XYZ     **CURRENT_CUST** ABC then,
**PREV_CUST** ABC     **CURRENT_CUST** DEF
```

I am not able to sort it out correctly.

Regards,
SV

```
CREATE TABLE PREV_DAY (ID NUMBER, CHANGE_TIME DATE, PROD_ID NUMBER, CUSTOMER VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE CURR_DAY (ID NUMBER, CHANGE_TIME DATE, PROD_ID NUMBER, CUSTOMER VARCHAR2(10), RANKING NUMBER);

INSERT INTO PREV_DAY VALUES (1, SYSDATE-1, 100, 'XYZ');
INSERT INTO PREV_DAY VALUES (2, SYSDATE-1, 200, 'EFG');

INSERT INTO CURR_DAY VALUES (1, SYSDATE, 100, 'ABC', 2);
INSERT INTO CURR_DAY VALUES (2, SYSDATE, 100, 'DEF', 1);
INSERT INTO CURR_DAY VALUES (3, SYSDATE, 200, 'IJK', 1);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I just can't figure out the motivation for this data structure.  You have a different table for every day ?!?

Comment: agree with Gordon no need for multiple tables here.  then just oracle lead, lag functions to get what you need

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry if I confused you guys. There are no such tables but I created them to provide a simplistic representation. The idea is, for a product, if any customer is changed, we have to select every change from last day to current day. We have to start with the latest customer on previous day for a product.

Comment: @user9256753 . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with the proper data that you are really using, along with an explanation and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `change_time` and `ranking` (descending) to sort. For data you provided it will be something like:

```
select change_time, ranking, prev, curr
  from (
    select lag(customer) over (order by change_time, ranking desc) prev, 
           customer curr, change_time, ranking
      from (select id, change_time, prod_id, customer, ranking 
              from curr_day where prod_id = 100 
            union all
            select id, change_time, prod_id, customer, null    
              from prev_day where prod_id = 100) )
  where change_time >= trunc(sysdate)
```

If data is in one table you don't need `union`, filter dates.

Result:

```
CHANGE_TIME          RANKING  PREV        CURR
-------------------  -------  ----------  ----------
2018-01-23 15:04:01        2  XYZ         ABC
2018-01-23 15:04:01        1  ABC         DEF
```